# pandas df elements from list into column

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, transpose

I have this DF:

| Elemento_lista | DISPLAYNAME | Rdo_Encontrado |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 90S VALASION | [('90S VALASION', 100, 0), ('90S VALASION', 100, 1), ('90S VALASION', 100, 2), ('90S VALASION', 100, 3)] |
| 1 | ADIZERO RC 2 W | [('ADIZERO RC 2 W', 100, 11), ('ADIZERO RC 2 W', 100, 12), ('ADIZERO RC 2 W', 100, 13), ('ADIZERO RC 2 W', 100, 14)] |
| 2 | ASWEERUN | [('ASWEERUN', 100, 16), ('ASWEERUN', 100, 17), ('90S VALASION', 34, 0), ('90S VALASION', 34, 1)] |

As it can bee seen, **Rdo_Encontrado** Column´s value is a List. I need a new row, for each element, and 3 new columns, with values from each list element. The Output should look like this:

| Elemento_lista | DISPLAYNAME | Coincidencia | Score | idx |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 90S VALASION | 90S VALASION | 100 | 0 |
| 0 | 90S VALASION | 90S VALASION | 100 | 1 |
| 0 | 90S VALASION | 90S VALASION | 100 | 2 |
| 0 | 90S VALASION | 90S VALASION | 100 | 3 |
| 1 | ADIZERO RC 2 W | ADIZERO RC 2 W | 100 | 11 |
| 1 | ADIZERO RC 2 W | ADIZERO RC 2 W | 100 | 12 |
| 1 | ADIZERO RC 2 W | ADIZERO RC 2 W | 100 | 13 |
| 1 | ADIZERO RC 2 W | ADIZERO RC 2 W | 100 | 14 |
| 2 | ASWEERUN | ASWEERUN | 100 | 16 |
| 2 | ASWEERUN | ASWEERUN | 100 | 17 |
| 2 | ASWEERUN | ASWEERUN | 34 | 0 |
| 2 | ASWEERUN | ASWEERUN | 34 | 1 |

Is it possible to do something like this?. I couldn´t find a way...

Comment: `explode()` will get you individual rows and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491274/split-a-pandas-column-of-lists-into-multiple-columns) will expand your tuple elements to columns

Comment: Hi, @G.Anderson, thanks for the answer , but but it´s not working for me...After df = df.explode ("Rdo_Encontrado") I get the Rdo_encontrado column with only one value in each row, so I have no values to expand in column, there is only one per row...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
# make sure you don't have strings in Rdo_Encontrado column:

from ast import literal_eval
df["Rdo_Encontrado"] = df["Rdo_Encontrado"].apply(literal_eval)



df = df.explode("Rdo_Encontrado")
df[["Coincidencia", "Score", "idx"]] = df.pop("Rdo_Encontrado").apply(pd.Series)
print(df.to_markdown())
```

Prints:

|  | Elemento_lista | DISPLAYNAME | Coincidencia | Score | idx |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 90S VALASION | 90S VALASION | 100 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 90S VALASION | 90S VALASION | 100 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 90S VALASION | 90S VALASION | 100 | 2 |
| 0 | 0 | 90S VALASION | 90S VALASION | 100 | 3 |
| 1 | 1 | ADIZERO RC 2 W | ADIZERO RC 2 W | 100 | 11 |
| 1 | 1 | ADIZERO RC 2 W | ADIZERO RC 2 W | 100 | 12 |
| 1 | 1 | ADIZERO RC 2 W | ADIZERO RC 2 W | 100 | 13 |
| 1 | 1 | ADIZERO RC 2 W | ADIZERO RC 2 W | 100 | 14 |
| 2 | 2 | ASWEERUN | ASWEERUN | 100 | 16 |
| 2 | 2 | ASWEERUN | ASWEERUN | 100 | 17 |
| 2 | 2 | ASWEERUN | 90S VALASION | 34 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | ASWEERUN | 90S VALASION | 34 | 1 |

---

EDIT: Added `ast.literal_eval`

Comment: Hi @Andrej Kesely, thanks for the answer, but it´s not working for me...After `df = df.explode ("Rdo_Encontrado")` I get the Rdo_encontrado column with only one value in each row, so after `df[["Coincidencia", "Score", "idx"]] = df.pop("Rdo_Encontrado").apply(pd.Series)`, I get this error:


ValueError: Columns must be same length as key

Comment: @MaximilianoVazquez I've edited my answer. Make sure you don't have string in `Rdo_Encontrado` column. Convert it to python lists with `ast.literal_eval` first.